# How to find two or more equal strings stored in two different vectors in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have two vectors (of different size) with strings in a data file.
I want to find the locations of two (or more) similar strings in each of these vectors. 
E.g.:

```
a=['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6'];
b=['str3', 'str1', 'str4', 'str4'];
```

I want an output like:

```
b(1) corresponds to a(3)
b(2) corresponds to a(1)
b(3) corresponds to a(4)
b(4) corresponds to a(4)
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you store your strings in cell arrays, you can do it like this:

```
>> a = {'str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6'};
>> b = {'str3', 'str1', 'str4', 'str4'};
>> result = cellfun(@(x) find(strcmp(a, x)), b, 'UniformOutput', false);

result = 

    [3]    [1]    [4]    [4]
```

**Note:** result is a cell array. Therefore, `result{i} == j` means `b(i)` corresponds to `a(j)`. If `b(i)` was not found in `a`, `result{i}` is empty.

Comment: Did you run all three commands above? What is your Matlab version?

Comment: MATLAB Version 7.0.1.24704 (R14) Service Pack 1, 2004

Comment: I've edited my answer, try again, please - I've changed `strcmp(x, a)` to `strcmp(a, x)`.

Comment: >> a = {'str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6'};
>> b = {'str3', 'str1', 'str4', 'str4'};
>> result = cellfun(@(x) find(strcmp(a, x)), b, 'UniformOutput', false)
??? Too many inputs.

Comment: Probably either `cellfun` or `strcmp` expect different arguments on your Matlab version. It works on Matlab R2013b. I suggest you look at the documentation to see alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the **ismember** command which will return an array of logicals indicating whether the element of array **b** is a member of array **a**.  It can also return a vector which indicates where in **a** the element of **b** is found.  Using your example:

```
[ismem,idxa]=ismember(b,a)
```

returns the results

```
ismem =
 1     1     1     1
idxa =
 3     1     4     4
```

So we see that each member of **b** is in **a** (due to the ismem vector being all ones) and we see where in **a** is that element of **b** from the idxa vector.  (Note that if **b** has an element that is not in **a** then there would be a zero element in both vectors.)

Comment: It's a good practice to either check for 0s in the 2nd output as `assert(all(idxa~=0),'Missing element(s) in a')` or remove 0s `idxa(idxa==0)=[];` before further operations with `idxa`.